# call javascript function from new window

Tags: javascript, scope

sorry this problem might be resolved already, but I have not been able to find the answer.

I basically have 2 files:

**form.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BACKUP MONITOR</title>
<script>
    function getEvents()
    {
        alert("getEvents");
    }

    alert("in HTML");

    var w = window.open();

    var s = w.document.createElement("script");
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = ".../fileA.js";
    w.document.body.appendChild(s);

    w.alert("New Window");
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**fileA.js** code:

```
alert("in fileA");
getEvents();
```

**Question:**

I can't call getEvents() from fileA.js (new Window). Is there any way to do this?

thank you very much

Comment: Include `fileA.js` after `getEvents` function is defined in your `form.html` !

Comment: why you put script code in html and calling in script

Comment: Hi ToKen and SivaRajini. The point of this exercise is to create a new Window, add the js file and call an getEvents from there.